# kubernetes with multiple jobs counter

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

New to kubernetes i´m trying to move a current pipeline we have using a queing  system without k8s.

I have a perl script that generates a list of batch jobs (yml files) for each of the samples that i have to process.
Then i run `kubectl apply --recursive -f 16S_jobscripts/`

For example each sample needs to be treated sequentially and go through different processing

Exemple:

SampleA -> clean -> quality -> some_calculation

SampleB -> clean -> quality -> some_calculation

and so on for 300 samples.

So the idea is to prepare all the yml files and run them sequentially. This is working.

BUT, with this approach i need to wait that all samples are processed (let´s say that all the clean jobs need to completed before i run the next jobs quality).

what would be the best approach in such case, run each sample independently ?? how ?

The yml below describe one Sample for one job. You can see that i´m using a counter (mergereads-1 for sample1(A))

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: merge-reads-1
  namespace: namespace-id-16s
  labels:
    jobgroup: mergereads
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: mergereads-1
      labels:
        jobgroup: mergereads
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mergereads-$idx
          image: .../bbmap:latest
          command: ['sh', '-c']
          args: ['
          cd workdir &&

          bbmerge.sh -Xmx1200m in1=files/trimmed/1.R1.trimmed.fq.gz in2=files/trimmed/1.R2.trimmed.fq.gz  out=files/mergedpairs/1.merged.fq.gz  merge=t mininsert=300 qtrim2=t minq=27 ratiomode=t &&
          ls files/mergedpairs/ 
          ']

          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 2000Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 0.8
              memory: 1500Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: '/workdir'
              name: db
      volumes:
        - name: db
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: workdir
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Does SampleA need to complete clean -> quality -> some_calculation before SampleB can begin? Can you flesh out in more detail the current workflow vs. the desired workflow? It's really difficult to follow based on what you provided so far.

Comment: I would like each sample can run independently of each other. So SAMPLEA->clean->then quality->then some calculation
Ideally i would like each SAMPLE to run independently of each other.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you can use [parallel-jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#parallel-jobs) with a use of [Job Patterns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-patterns).

> It does support parallel processing of a set of independent but
>   related work items.

Also you can consider using Argo.
https://github.com/argoproj/argo

> Argo Workflows is an open source container-native workflow engine for
>   orchestrating parallel jobs on Kubernetes. Argo Workflows is
>   implemented as a Kubernetes CRD (Custom Resource Definition).

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi , yes it helps. Sorry for my description, was not clear enough. But definetly i´m going to look into argo , seems like appropriate to run all the samples in parallel. Do you know of any tutorial or simple exemple using either Job patterns ?

Comment: Good to hear that. I have found some [examples](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/tree/master/examples) you might find useful.